¿Porque android studio me lanza java.lang.NullPointerException si no he escrito nada aun?

En la imagen se ve el IDE Android studio listo para comenzar a desarrollar codigo, el codigo que muestra es el que lleva al inicar un proyecto con el IDE.

¿Qué ves en el Logcat?
